# Pansharpening of atmospheric corrected image

Tags: pansharpening

After applying any atmospheric correction on raw MS and Pan image we get the DN value between 0 and 1 as we know reflectance is unit less or just ratio of input irradiance and radiance after this atmospheric correction pan sharpened is possible?

Or

Should we first apply pan sharpened then spread pansharpened bands then apply atmospheric correction?

Answer (score 1):

PanSharpening is a process of merging high-resolution panchromatic and lower resolution multispectral imagery to create a single high-resolution color image. Google Maps and nearly every map creating company use this technique to increase image quality. So, to answer your question. It is the last process to use in order to enhance the resolution thus you should apply all other corrections before it.

Comment: after  these correction when i pan sharp using PCA algorithm in erdas result of pan sharp is zero but when i use HPF merge technique this showing result and OBIA is not run on this atmospheric correction image

Comment: did you apply the radiometric correction first? use FLAASH in ENVI. Erdas is not the "best" at this.

Comment: yes first i convert DN value into TOA radiance then apply 6S atmospheric correction

Comment: try exporting your atmospheric correction data into a .tif or .img image

Comment: data already in tif format

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your application is. There are two broad use cases:
A - creating better looking imagery. 
B - creating a higher quality scientific product for spectral analysis.

In case A you're best to experiment, it depends on the sensor and the algorithm.

Case B is more complicated and even more use specific. Unless you have a good reason to believe pansharpening will improve your data (ie either  something peer reviewed  AND convincing AND the same use case as yourself, or if your in a position to check for yourself on verifying sample data) it is best not to alter it as you simply reduce the repeatability and therefore potential verification of your science. 
This would be a good place to stay reading about the issues with reference to vegetation indicies and landsat 8.
https://gisandscience.com/2014/07/09/effects-of-pansharpening-on-vegetation-indices/

Comment: i m working on coral reef using landsat 8 to avoid mixing of different features or species i decide pan sharpaneing